# How to create a ResponseEntity from HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

I would like to retrieve the response from HttpURLConnection  into ResponseEntity. I got the 406 error.

Thank you in advance.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrive", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public ResponseEntity<?> retrive (HttpServletRequest request){
        //1. call a rest by rest client
        URL u = new URL("http://localhost:8080/getHello");
        HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

        //2, create HttpHeaders for ResponseEntity
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
          String headerName = uc.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
          String headerValue = uc.getHeaderField(i);
          if(headerName != null && headerValue != null){
            responseHeaders.set(headerName, headerValue);
          }
          if (headerName == null && headerValue == null) {
            break;
          }
        }
        //3. create ResponseEntity
        InputStream inputStream = uc.getInputStream();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(inputStream, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to build some kind of reverse proxy then you can just copy from input stream to the output stream:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/retrive", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
  public ResponseEntity<?> retrive (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    //1. call a rest by rest client
    URL u = new URL("http://localhost:8080/getHello");
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

    //2, create HttpHeaders for ResponseEntity
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
      String headerName = uc.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
      String headerValue = uc.getHeaderField(i);
      if(headerName != null && headerValue != null){
        responseHeaders.set(headerName, headerValue);
      }
      if (headerName == null && headerValue == null) {
        break;
      }
    }

    try (InputStream inputStream = uc.getInputStream();
         OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        )
    {
      IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
    //3. create ResponseEntity
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, what you need is to redirect the call to this other url ?

```
@RequestMapping(path="/retrieve", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void stack(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip");
    }
```

This way, you are not playing man-in-middle reading and writing the content.

Otherwise,I've also updated the previous answer, which should allow you to avoid an out of memory error:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public void retrieve(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    URL u = new URL("http://localhost:8080/getHello");
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    try (InputStream imageStream = u.openStream()) {
        IOUtils.copy(imageStream, outputStream );
    }
}
```

IOUtils.copy basically reads/writes the input in chunks, instead of reading the whole response in one step.

You need commons-io for one `IOUtils`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, 

thanks for your reply.

The getHello service return a string "hello".

If "byte[]" is too big, than I got the out of memory error. I would like to retrieve(now the word is correct :-)) the InputStream directly.

Comment: updated the answer with a suggestion to do a sendRedirect

Comment: Thank you for your answer and solution.

Comment: If @DenysKurylenko's solution works for you, you could always accept it :)(he also suggested the use IOUtils.copy, we provided this solution simultaneously, I suggest you accept his as a welcome-to-stackoverflow)